# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name - looking for logfile with more details

Tags: java, jsp

I am working with probably a 15 year old version of Apache Server running under Oracle 9i.  I copied a working jsp page and edited it ( manually with vi ).  Now I am getting the following exception:
I am trying to find a detailed log file that might tell me what column it does not like. I know just enough about web development to be dangerous...
A few things I am looking at:
Is the error due to a string variable name that is too long ( not sure what max length might be)
Is it due to a date to string issue?  I used Oracle to_char to convert date to string

I am trying to find a logfile that might give more detail.

```
Exception:
    java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:269)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.get_column_index(OracleStatement.java:6240)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1557)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:1482)
    at _prod._htdocs._test._PSU__report__all._jspService(_PSU__report__all.java:121)
    at oracle.jsp.runtime.HttpJsp.service(HttpJsp.java)
    at oracle.jsp.app.JspApplication.dispatchRequest(JspApplication.java)
    at oracle.jsp.JspServlet.doDispatch(JspServlet.java)
    at oracle.jsp.JspServlet.internalService(JspServlet.java)
    at oracle.jsp.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:588)
    at org.apache.jserv.JServConnection.processRequest(JServConnection.java:456)
    at org.apache.jserv.JServConnection.run(JServConnection.java:294)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:513)
```

Comment: What is the exact SQL query ?

Comment: can you please mentioned the select query and my guess is you are may be using TO_CHAR (realdate, 'YYYYMMDD') and searching column with realdate

Comment: I found my typo , so my page is now working, but I would styill like to know where to find any logfiles.  I found access_log and error_log, but cannot find any other log files.
My typo was in getString :  I misspelled the required_patch field name:

    v_required_patch = listset.getString("requiired_patch");